# В пух и прах

Tags: фразеология

Разгромить противника в пух и прах - так говорят, имея в виду полную победу над врагом. Но вот интересно, почему именно в пух и почему в прах? То есть, каждое из этих слов само по себе понятно: пух, видимо, подразумевается тот, что остается от ощипанной птицы. Прах - как бы тоже понятно: то, что остается от убитого врага. Но как это сочетается вместе?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Первоначально слова пух и прах были связаны с глаголами, обозначавшими конкретные действия: с пуши/ть/распуши/ть "взбивать/взбить или, взбивая, расчёсывать/расчесать лежалую, свалявшуюся шерсть, волосы и т. п." (букв. "делать/сделать пухлым, как пух"), а также с архаизмами праши/ть/распраши/ть, пороши/ть/распороши/ть "дробить/раздробить на мелкие частички, превращать/превратить в прах, в пыль". Самостоятельно употреблялись и выражения разбить в пух "взбивая, распушить", разбить в прах "раздробить в порошок, измельчить в пыль, ударяя". Отсюда переносные значения "разгромить" и "сильно отругать" (ср. распушить "разбранить"). В дальнейшем в связи со сходством значений произошло слияние двух оборотов в один, расширение значения и сочетаемости. метафорически отражается мифологическое, т. е. свойственное древнейшему окультуренному осознанию мира, представление о прахе как о том, откуда взят человек и куда он вернётся после кончины. см. в библейском тексте: "В поте лица твоего будешь есть хлеб, доколе не возвратишься в землю, из которой ты взят; ибо прах ты и в прах возвратишься".

Источник: http://phrase_dictionary.academic.ru/169/%D0%92_%D0%9F%D0%A3%D0%A5_%D0%98_%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%A5